# How to get current line string without visual selection?

Tags: command-line, selection

I'm usually working with a file list for sorting/deleting/etc files, and I like to sometimes run arbitrary command on those files (which have either a full path or already present in current directory).

Now, I do know i can always make a mapping with visual selection, that would then just select current line and use it with [command here], but i was wondering if there was a better way, especially since other things like `<cWORD>` don't need visual selection, but alas only work on current word.

```
.w !commandhere
```

This work fine for things like `bash` but, if I need the input to be in front, then it (obviously) doesn't work.
I recall managing to do this using:

```
.w !commandhere %
```

But that didn't work here. (edit: Nevermind on this part, just learned that `%` is actually the currently opened file's filename...)

Here I tried a couple things with `getline`:

```
.w !commandhere execute getline('.')
```

This doesn't work, but:

```
execute getline('.')
```

This work in at least getting the actual string (in the message/error buffer I presume?).

Lastly, this one got closer to the solution:

```
exec '!commandhere '.getline('.')
```

But still not it yet. (guessing this isn't working because of space/parentheses in the filenames)

I already know how to make it as a mapping. Just wondering if there other ways to do this *without* using visual selection, for the current line (where the blinking cursor is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close!

You can use [`shellescape()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#shellescape%28%29) to quote the argument to pass it to the shell, which will take care of spaces and any shell metacharacters that might be present in the line.

```
exec '!commandhere '.shellescape(getline('.'))
```